# Connecting Lucee v5.3.8.201 and IIS10.0.19041

Tags: iis, lucee

I'm trying to convert web sites from Adobe ColdFusion (ACF) to the open source Lucee instead.

My issue is to make sure all my previous ACF work runs without error in Lucee before I upload it to the web. I have been able to install Lucee (v5.3.8.201) with Tomcat9, BonCodeAJP13 and Mod_CFML  which I've been assured is what I need to have it all working together so I can test my sites (11 of them at the moment).

However I have some problems that I can't seem to find an answer to. The docs don't cover using a PC as a dev machine if it has multiple web sites on it. And IIS is the old version that's still used in Windows Server not Windows 10.

1. How do I get to the Lucee administrator What's the address for that? I need that to set up datasources for my sites of they're going to fail on the very first page.
2. How do I actually make sites defined in IIS10 work through Lucee? I have run the connector and TomCat is running, but the browser doesn't recognise any Lucee pages except the initial "Welcome to Lucee" page.

Comment: **[A]** `http://hostname:port/lucee/admin/server.cfm`

Comment: `IIS is the old version that's still used in Windows Server not Windows10.` Either windows or windows server can get IIS. And IIS 10 can be get from Windows 10 and Windows 11.